# Metric 'it_lines_cover' should not be computed by a Sensor

Tags: sonarqube, sensors, metric

I've got an error during phpunit coverage report parsing with SonarQube Scanner 2.8 with following message :

```
Metric 'it_lines_to_cover' should not be computed by a Sensor
```

Thanks in advance,

**Versions** :

```
10:42:57.262 INFO: SonarQube Scanner 2.8
10:42:57.262 INFO: Java 1.8.0_111 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
10:42:57.262 INFO: Linux 3.13.0-103-generic amd64
10:43:08.803 DEBUG:   * PHP 2.9.1.1705 (php)
```

**Error log** :

```
10:43:18.046 INFO: Sensor PHP sensor
10:43:18.420 INFO: 78 source files to be analyzed
10:43:21.533 INFO: 78/78 source files have been analyzed
10:43:21.543 INFO: PHPUnit xml test report not found: tests/build
/logs/junit_unit.xml
10:43:21.544 INFO: PHPUnit xml unit test coverage report not found: 
tests/build/logs/clover-unit.xml
10:43:21.544 INFO: Analyzing PHPUnit integration test coverage report: 
tests/build/logs/clover-integration.xml with PHPUnit IT Coverage Result Parser
10:43:21.544 DEBUG: Parsing file: /home/travis/build/armadito
/glpi/plugins/armadito/tests/build/logs/clover-integration.xml
10:43:23.079 DEBUG: Coverage metrics have not been set on 'index.php': 
default values will be inserted.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:43:23.084 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
10:43:23.084 INFO: 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:43:23.515 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Metric 'it_lines_to_cover' should not be computed by a Sensor
at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.DefaultSensorStorage.saveMeasure(DefaultSensorStorage.java:240)
at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.DefaultSensorStorage.store(DefaultSensorStorage.java:213)
at org.sonar.api.batch.sensor.measure.internal.DefaultMeasure.doSave(DefaultMeasure.java:93)
at org.sonar.api.batch.sensor.internal.DefaultStorable.save(DefaultStorable.java:43)
at org.sonar.plugins.php.phpunit.PhpUnitCoverageResultParser.saveMeasureForMissingFiles(PhpUnitCoverageResultParser.java:129)
at org.sonar.plugins.php.phpunit.PhpUnitCoverageResultParser.parseFile(PhpUnitCoverageResultParser.java:102)
at org.sonar.plugins.php.phpunit.PhpUnitCoverageResultParser.parse(PhpUnitCoverageResultParser.java:84)
at org.sonar.plugins.php.phpunit.PhpUnitService.parseReport(PhpUnitService.java:74)
at org.sonar.plugins.php.phpunit.PhpUnitService.execute(PhpUnitService.java:60)
at org.sonar.plugins.php.PHPSensor.processCoverage(PHPSensor.java:142)
at org.sonar.plugins.php.PHPSensor.execute(PHPSensor.java:132)
```

Comment: Would be interesting to know your SonarQube server version.

Comment: I use SonarQube.com, so at that time it is : 13:18:57.974 INFO: SonarQube server 6.2-RC2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message will disappear once https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARPHP-658 is implemented. It is scheduled for next release of the PHP plugin.

Comment: Thanks a lot, is there any way to fasten PHP plugin's update on sonarqube.com ? Indeed, SonarQube.com's installed plugin is still at version 2.9.1.1705 (php).

Comment: Thanks, I confirm, bug fixed.

Comment: @JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam, I am facing the same issue and using the version 6.2 of the SonarQube, what was the solution exactly?

Comment: @gaurav Check you are using up to date version of the SonarQube language plugins.